# SSMS crashes when trying to run SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms-2014

I have SSMS 2014 along with SQL Server 2014 database.  I'm trying to set up a package deployment model.  As soon as I right click the package under the Integration Services Catalogs and click Execute I get the Execute Package popup.  I select the environment and OK.  SSMS crashes with a popup that says SQL Server Management Studio has stopped working, the it restarts itself.  No other error message.  How can I troubleshoot this?  The package runs fine in SSIS designer.  Where is the SSMS log?

Resolved: About the 10th time I tried executing the package the crash popup included a button to debug.  Looking at this indicated the problem was a missing: 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=12.0.0.0.  Downloading and installing ReportViewer from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496 fixed the immediate problem.

Comment: What version of BIDS was used to create the package?

Comment: About the 10th time I tried executing the package the crash popup included a button to debug.  Looking at this indicated the problem was a missing: 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=12.0.0.0.  Downloading and installing ReportViewer from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496 fixed the immediate problem.